# Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app on heroku, bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am not able to upload a ruby application in Heroku, I have done several searches on the error, but nothing worked, could anyone help me? follows error log:

> -----> Ruby app detected 
>   -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails 
>   -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4 
>   -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2 
>          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment 
>          Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......... 
>          Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. 
>          Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/. 
>          Fetching rake 10.5.0 
>          Fetching i18n 0.7.0 
>          Using json 1.8.3 
>          Fetching minitest 5.8.4 
>          Installing i18n 0.7.0 
>          Installing minitest 5.8.4 
>          Installing rake 10.5.0 
>          Fetching thread_safe 0.3.5 
>          Installing thread_safe 0.3.5 
>          Fetching builder 3.2.2 
>          Installing builder 3.2.2 
>          Fetching erubis 2.7.0 
>          Fetching nokogiri 1.6.7.2 
>          Fetching rack 1.6.4 
>  
>          Installing erubis 2.7.0 
>          Installing rack 1.6.4 
>          Fetching mime-types 2.6.1 
>  
>          Installing mime-types 2.6.1 
>          Fetching arel 6.0.3 
>          Installing arel 6.0.3 
>          Using bundler 1.15.2 
>          Fetching coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1 
>          Fetching execjs 2.6.0 
>          Installing execjs 2.6.0 
>          Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1 
>          Fetching thor 0.19.1 
>          Fetching multi_json 1.11.2 
>          Installing thor 0.19.1 
>          Installing multi_json 1.11.2 
>          Fetching pg 1.0.0 
>          Installing pg 1.0.0 with native extensions 
>          Using rdoc 4.2.1 
>          Fetching sass 3.4.21 
>          Installing sass 3.4.21 
>          Fetching tilt 2.0.8 
>          Installing tilt 2.0.8 
>          Fetching tzinfo 1.2.2 
>          Installing tzinfo 1.2.2 
>          Fetching rack-test 0.6.3 
>          Installing rack-test 0.6.3 
>          Fetching sprockets 3.3.0 
>          Fetching mail 2.6.3 
>          Installing sprockets 3.3.0 
>          Fetching uglifier 2.7.2 
>          Installing mail 2.6.3 
>          Installing uglifier 2.7.2 
>          Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1 
>          Installing coffee-script 2.4.1 
>          Fetching sdoc 0.4.1 
>          Installing sdoc 0.4.1 
>          Downloading nokogiri-1.6.7.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
>          lockfile (mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)).
>          Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update nokogiri` should
>          fix the problem. 
>          Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......... 
>          Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. 
>          Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/. 
>          Fetching rake 10.5.0 
>          Fetching i18n 0.7.0 
>          Using json 1.8.3 
>          Fetching minitest 5.8.4 
>          Installing i18n 0.7.0 
>          Installing minitest 5.8.4 
>          Installing rake 10.5.0 
>          Fetching thread_safe 0.3.5 
>          Installing thread_safe 0.3.5 
>          Fetching builder 3.2.2 
>          Installing builder 3.2.2 
>          Fetching erubis 2.7.0 
>          Fetching nokogiri 1.6.7.2 
>          Fetching rack 1.6.4 
>          Installing erubis 2.7.0 
>          Installing rack 1.6.4 
>          Fetching mime-types 2.6.1 
>          Installing mime-types 2.6.1 
>          Fetching arel 6.0.3 
>          Installing arel 6.0.3 
>          Using bundler 1.15.2 
>          Fetching coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1 
>          Fetching execjs 2.6.0 
>          Installing execjs 2.6.0 
>          Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1 
>          Fetching thor 0.19.1 
>          Fetching multi_json 1.11.2 
>  
>          Installing thor 0.19.1 
>          Installing multi_json 1.11.2 
>          Fetching pg 1.0.0 
>          Installing pg 1.0.0 with native extensions 
>          Using rdoc 4.2.1 
>          Fetching sass 3.4.21 
>          Installing sass 3.4.21 
>          Fetching tilt 2.0.8 
>          Installing tilt 2.0.8 
>          Fetching tzinfo 1.2.2 
>          Installing tzinfo 1.2.2 
>          Fetching rack-test 0.6.3 
>          Installing rack-test 0.6.3 
>          Fetching sprockets 3.3.0 
>          Fetching mail 2.6.3 
>          Installing sprockets 3.3.0 
>          Fetching uglifier 2.7.2 
>          Installing mail 2.6.3 
>          Installing uglifier 2.7.2 
>          Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1 
>          Installing coffee-script 2.4.1 
>          Fetching sdoc 0.4.1 
>          Installing sdoc 0.4.1 
>          Downloading nokogiri-1.6.7.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
>          lockfile (mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)).
>          Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update nokogiri` should
>          fix the problem. 
>   ! 
>   !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>   ! 
>   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby
>   app.
>   !     Push failed

Follow my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.6)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.4)
    binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.21)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.6)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (1.0.0)
    rack (1.6.8)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activerecord (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.6)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    sass (3.5.5)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.5)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.6)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` locally?

Comment: Also, please run `bundle update nokogiri` locally to ensure it makes it into the lock file.

Comment: Hi, Yes and the result about the bundle install is: Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Comment: bundle update nokogiri ---> Bundler attempted to update nokogiri but its version stayed the same
Bundle updated! but doens'r works :/

Answer (score 0):

run `bundle update` on your local repo and upload those changes to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall the nokogiri gem and then reinstall it and try bundle install again.

If that doesn't work you can try running

```
bundle lock --update=nokogiri
bundle install
```

If neither of those work I've seen that downgrading bundler to version 1.14.6 might do the trick.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help :)

Unfortunately nothing worked: /

Comment: root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# gem uninstall nokogiri
Successfully uninstalled nokogiri-1.8.2

root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# gem install nokogiri
Fetching: nokogiri-1.8.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.8.2
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.8.2
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.8.2
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 26 seconds
1 gem installed

Comment: root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# bundle install
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.


root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# bundle lock --update=nokogiri
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Writing lockfile to /home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip/Gemfile.lock

Comment: root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# bundle install
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# gem uninstall bundler
Successfully uninstalled bundler-1.16.1

Comment: root@TI:/home/mario/Área de Trabalho/rubyandrails/moip# gem install bundler --version '1.14.6'
Fetching: bundler-1.14.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
1 gem installed

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `vendor/bundle/ruby/<ruby version no>/gems` there should be `nokogiri-1.6.7.2` but you need `nokogiri-1.8.2`

I've resolved this issue in the past by:

```
cd vendor/bundle/ruby; rm -rf <ruby version nos>
```

and then run `bundle install` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but that also did not work :(